# Saving multiple models simultaneously in Strongloop

Tags: node.js, forms, rest, relationships, strongloop

I'm developing an app that is entirely based on a StrongLoop REST API as backend.

There is a single registration form. The user fills in personal details and also some details about the company he/she works for. The user and company are separate models, and have a "has one" relation.

What is the best way of validating + saving a form to both models at the same time? (preferably in one request)

There are a few things that would make this possible but I couldn't find any documentation about it, or it's kind of ugly:

- A POST request that includes the related company model, similar to the filter[include] option that exists on GET requests.
- A way of getting validation errors without actually saving the models, so you can save the whole form after both models validate (however, requires multiple requests)
- Send the whole form to the user model, and save the company model server side.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished using Hooks: **Remote hooks** and **Operation hooks**

Remote hooks are triggers that are invoked before or after a remote is invoked.

Operation hook is triggered from all methods that execute a particular high-level create, read, update, or delete (CRUD) "operation".   These are all methods of PersistedModel that application models inherit. 
Example of Remote hook: this goes into the .js part of common/models

```
Person.afterRemote('create', function (context, Person, cb) {
        var Role = app.models.Role;
        var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;
        Role.findOne({
            where: {
                name: 'customer'
            }
        }, function (err, role) {
            role.principals.create({
                    principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
                    principalId: Person.id
                },
                function (err, principal) {
                    if (err) cb(err);
                    ...
                });
        });
```

Example of Operation hooks:

```
Company.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
  console.log('Going to save employee..');
  next();
});
```

Comment: I'm aware of hooks, but how exactly would this work? Do I post the attributes from both the user and company in one request, and then using a hook save the company model separately?

Comment: yeah, that's the way I was able do. This way only one request will be there and one object is saved in the callback of another object's save.